# Operator not defined for list of custom class

Tags: vb.net, list, class

I have created a custom class `Node` and have defined the `=` operator for it.

However, upon attempting to use the `=` operator with a `List(Of Node)`, I have been told that the `=` operator is not defined for the `List(Of Node)`. I suppose I assumed that as I had defined the operator for the class that it would work similarly for a collection class.

Anyway, I do not know how to go about defining the operator when it is an already existing collection such as a list and would appreciate some pointers in the right direction.
Any help is much appreciated and I can provide code snippets if you would find it useful :)
Thanks

EDIT
Operators in class

```
Public Shared Operator =(ByVal nodeA As Node, ByVal nodeB As Node) As Boolean 'Defining what the operators '=' and '<>' mean for this class and type
    If nodeA.xPos = nodeB.xPos And nodeA.yPos = nodeB.yPos Then 'Decided should be determined by whether they hold the same position in the grid
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal nodeA As Node, ByVal nodeB As Node) As Boolean
    If nodeA.xPos = nodeB.xPos And nodeA.yPos = nodeB.yPos Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Operator
```

Where I have attempted to check if the list is null ...

```
If path = Nothing Then


End If
```

... and got 'Operator '=' is not defined for types List(of Node) and List(of Node)

Comment: You can extend List as well! Define the `=` operator on that class instead.

Comment: You might want to add some code demonstrating what you have and how you are trying to use an operator with a list.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @kingdamian42 May you explain how I do so? I attempted to write that class but couldn't seem to inherit the default list class, so ended up losing all functionality of a list. Not entirely sure what I am doing haha

Comment: @Plutonix I have added some pictures of the code I am working with. I am needing to check if a list of my custom class is null, however am struggling to do so. Hopefully the attached images help explain a little better.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] right away.  We dont want pictures of code, but the actual real code in the question.  Its easier to paste code into the post than capturing a picture **and** it is easier to read for us.  Note that you did not just create a "custom class", but inherited button to make a *custom control*

Comment: @Plutonix I do apologise, I believe that should be better now. Perhaps my description was off also

Comment: There is no context for the actual error cited - that involving a `List<T>`.  A collection is different than the items in it - they are 2 different things entirely; you certainly cant compare a node/button to a list of them (thats the part we cant see - no idea what `path` is.  But when testing for null/Nothing it would be `If path Is Nothing Then...`

Comment: @Plutonix 'Is Nothing' was all that was needed. I apologise for the confusion as I did not know that when testing for null, is nothing was all that was needed. For reference (and don't take personal offence), the manner in which you explained this felt somewhat condescending. You evidently understood what I required by the last part of your answer, so as a suggestion, perhaps lead with that as it would have felt more encouraging.

Comment: No, I did not "obviously know" - we have no idea what you are comparing or where, .  I noted a basic syntax error based.  As for the rest, please carefully read the  above transcription.  Its exasperating to have to beg for salient details in order to provide help to someone.